# React power bi embedded showing old report after paramater update

Tags: reactjs, powerbi

I have a react app where i am using the powerbi-client-react package. I want to generate a report based on the location_id. Now when the location_id changes i want to update the report but now i have the problem that the values are being displayed in the report instead of the values for the new location_id?

This is my code:

```
import { useReport } from '../model/report-queries';
import styles from './styles.module.scss';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import { models } from 'powerbi-client';
import { IPaginatedReportParameter } from 'powerbi-models';

const ReportPage = () => {
  const { reportName = '' } = useParams();
  const { location_id } = useParams<{ location_id: string }>();
  const { query: ReportQuery } = useReport(reportName, location_id);

  // Define parameter values with the correct type
  const parameterValues: IPaginatedReportParameter[] = [{ name: 'LocationId', value: location_id || '' }];

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
      <PowerBIEmbed
        embedConfig={{
          type: EmbedType.Report,
          id: ReportQuery.data?.id,
          embedUrl: ReportQuery.data?.embedUrl,
          accessToken: ReportQuery.data?.accessToken,
          tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
          settings: {
            panes: {
              filters: {
                expanded: false,
                visible: false,
              },
            },
          },
          parameterValues: parameterValues,
        }}
        cssClassName={styles.PowerBi_Container}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReportPage;
```